# PyQt4 - Button.connect() recieves always last iteration index

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.6

Im doing a software with Python3.6, PyQt4 and SQlite3. The software consist in a number of students each of them with their data (unique id, name, surname, address, etc.) The GUI has a list menu, were the list of all the students is shown.

In the list itself, I iterate depending on how many students I have. The layout is made and it creates a name, and 2 QPushButtons (one to generate a PDF and other to delete the student data)

Here is an example

[image]

In my code, I have every "Generate a PDF" button of each student in the list on a python list, also for the "Delete student" buttons. 
My problem is when I give the buttons the .clicked.connect(function)

```
for i in range(0, len(self.list_menu.delete_button_list)):
    self.list_menu.delete_button_list[i].clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.delete_student_data(self.list_menu.id_list[i]))
```

For example, I have 3 students on the list, so button 1 should recieve id:1 `self.delete_student_data(1)`, then button_2 with id=2 and button_3 with id:=3. But from what I've understood, what .connect() recieves does not execute, not until the button is actually clicked in this case. So at the moment .connect() is called, the value i is 3 in this example. Hence every button call the `self.delete_student_data` with id=3.

I see that there is no way to make this work like I pretend to.

Hope its clear the way I described it. Thanks!

Comment: A tip for tagging in SO: always include the language tag (ie. “python”), if your issue is specific to python 3.6, add both tags, as “python-3.6” is an add-on tag to “python”. More people will read/answer your question when it’s properly tagged, since we usually only hangout in the “python” tag section. (I have edited your tag for this question, be aware next time)

Comment: Use a default argument: `connect(lambda arg, i=i: ...` (NB: the `arg` param is needed because the clicked signal always sends its checked state).

Comment: @ekhumoro I didn't understood the `arg` you are referring to, where arg is used? in my delete_student_data function? Thanks for the reply

Comment: @juanga13. You don't need to use it. But it has to be there, otherwise the signal would overwrite your `i` argument with a boolean value. The rest of your current `lambda` function can stay exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using functools.partial module. As from what I understand, partial takes the argument of the function and 'freezes' it. Maybe someone knows better this whole behavior and can explain it better. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html).

Now the code is the following:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.list_menu.delete_button_list)):
button = self.list_menu.delete_button_list[i]
button.clicked.connect(partial(self.delete_student_data, button))
```